# serve current directory from command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

could someone give me a hint, howto serve the current directory from command line with ruby? it would be great, if i can have some system wide configuration (e.g. mime-types) and simply launch it from every directory.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Simplest way possible (thanks [Aaron Patterson](https://twitter.com/tenderlove/status/351554818579505152)/n0kada):

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 9090
```

Alternate, more complex way:

```
ruby -r webrick -e "s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 9090, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd); trap('INT') { s.shutdown }; s.start"
```

---

Even the first command is hard to remember, so I just have this in my `.bashrc`:

```
function serve {
  port="${1:-3000}"
  ruby -run -e httpd . -p $port
}
```

It serves the current directory on port *3000* by default, but you can also specify the port:

```
~ $ cd tmp
~/tmp $ serve      # ~/tmp served on port 3000
~/tmp $ cd ../www
~/www $ serve 5000   # ~/www served on port 5000
```

Comment: If you're on windows, is it possible to add this to cmd or powershell as a function?

Comment: @Daniel - when I run your one liner on my Mac. I got this error message: uninitialized constant INT (NameError). Are you running it on a different platform? Do you know how I can avoid this? But if I write it into a file say myserver.rb then do "ruby myserver.rb", it works fine.

Comment: @TonyJiang I'm also running on a Mac. Tried it with Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3 and 2.0.0, and they all work. Weird.

Comment: To demistify `ruby -run -e httpd . -p 9090` look at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/un/rdoc/index.html.

It's executing httpd method from `un` ruby standard library, thus require un.

Comment: I wrote up a deeper explanation that might be of interest:  http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2013/09/13/ruby-simple-http-server-minimalist-rake/

Comment: His bash function is not to be confused with the `serve` gem which will serve the current directory but also render ERB, HAML, etc. http://get-serve.com/

Comment: What interface does this bind to?

Comment: Hey, I know this it's been a long time since this, but asking in case anybody knows. How would you leave this running in the background? Any special flag for it?

Comment: @Deviljho if you are running on Mac or Linux, just add an ampersand at the end of the command to send it to the background: `ruby -run -e httpd . -p 9090 &`

If you want to bring it back to the foreground, use `fg`.

Comment: Cool thanks!, a small question, how do you know this?

Comment: @Deviljho They are standard UNIX process management operations.

Answer (score 24):

As [Aaron Patterson](http://tenderlovemaking.com/) [tweeted it out](https://twitter.com/tenderlove/status/351554818579505152) today you can do:

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 5000
```

And you can set the bind address as well by adding `-b 127.0.0.1`

Works with Ruby 1.9.2 and greater.

Answer (score 23):

I've never seen anything as compact as

```
python3 -m http.server
```

You can optionally add a port number to the end:

```
python3 -m http.server 9000
```

See https://docs.python.org/library/http.server.html

Comment: There is a list of pretty compact solutions here: https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255 :)

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'webrick'
include WEBrick

s = HTTPServer.new(:Port => 9090,  :DocumentRoot => Dir::pwd)
trap("INT"){ s.shutdown }
s.start
```

Answer (score 5):

Use ruby gem [Serve](http://get-serve.com/).

To install on your system, run `gem install serve`.

To serve a directory, simply cd to the directory and run `serve`.

Default port is 4000. It can also serve things like ERB, HAML, Slim and SASS.

Answer (score 3):

#### Web Server in 1 line

This may or may not be quite what you want but it's so cool that I just had to share it.

I've used this in the past to serve the file system. Perhaps you could modify it or just accept that it serves everything.

```
ruby -rsocket -e 's=TCPServer.new(5**5);loop{_=s.accept;_<<"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n#{File.read(_.gets.split[1])rescue nil}";_.close}'
```

I found it [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5424)

Chris

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sinatra` gem, though it doesn't do any directory listing for you, it serves files:

```
require 'sinatra' # gem
set :public_folder, '.'
```

then run that as a file, if in 1.8 add require 'rubygems' to the top first.

After running it then url's like

http://localhost:4567/file_name

should resolve to "./file_name" file.

http://localhost:4567 won't work however, since it doesn't "do" directory listings.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12115019/32453 for a workaround there.

Comment: install the sinatra gem $ gem install sinatra then save this text to somefile.rb then run it

Comment: No, I mean, Sinatra gives me the error: Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.

Comment: @eveevans somehow just noticed your comment [LOL sorry], updated now.

Answer (score 1):

```
python3 -m http.server
```

or if you don't want to use the default port 8000

```
python3 -m http.server 3333
```

or if you want to allow connections from localhost only

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server).