# How can I view a list of my files in a directory on sinatra?

Tags: file, sinatra

I run an project on Sinatra, now it has a lot of files a sub-directories, so I want to view a list of those files with their respective directory.
For example, I put in the address bar "localhost:4567/landing/" where landing is the container of some pages, but it throw me this "Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty."
Is there a way to do that.
I hope you understand what  I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinatra doesn't deal with the local file system, it deals with HTTP routes. For example, the `'/'` in `get '/' do` refers to the root url of your website, not the root directory of your website. In order to list the local files, you would need to use the Ruby `Dir` class, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
   Dir.entries('.').map { |e| "<p>#{e}</p>" }
end
```

**Edit:** Of course, it's dangerous to work with the filesystem directly, even using routes, so I would recommend that you get a better understanding of what is going on behind the scenes by reading up a little.