# Simple file server to serve current directory

Tags: python, ruby, perl, node.js, shell

I'm looking for a dead simple bin that I can launch up in the shell and have it serve the current directory (preferably not ..), with maybe a `-p` for specifying port. As it should be a development server, it should by default allow connections from localhost only, maybe with an option to specify otherwise. The simpler, the better.

Not sure which tags to use here.

Comment: You should probably post this over on http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: ruby solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108395/serve-current-directory-from-command-line

Comment: Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.  When you do web development (and even other types of development nowadays) you end up needing to access local files via HTTP.  Perhaps this is still off-topic because it is asking for a tool recommendation, but I disagree on the closure reason given.

Comment: Vote to reopen.  This was useful for me today.  And the answers cover both Py2 & Py3.  I needed both!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
python3 -m http.server
```

or if you don't want to use the default port 8000

```
python3 -m http.server 3333
```

or if you want to allow connections from localhost only

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server).

---

The equivalent Python 2 commands are

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3333
```

There is no `--bind` option.

See the [Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server).

Comment: There is also a directory argument in case you don't want the current dir: `python3 -m http.server -d /path/to/web/dir`

Answer (score 16):

For Node, there's `http-server`:

```
$ npm install -g http-server
$ http-server Downloads -a localhost -p 8080
Starting up http-server, serving Downloads on port: 8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Python has:

- **Python 3**: `python -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 8080`
- **Python 2**: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

Note that Python 2 has no `--bind` option, so it will allow all connections (not just from `localhost`).

Comment: I'd like to see number of folders and directories as well

Answer (score 3):

There is the Perl app [App::HTTPThis](https://metacpan.org/module/http_this) or I have often used a tiny [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) server to do this. See my [blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2013/01/a-quick-static-file-webserver.html) from a while back.

Make a file called say `server.pl`. Put this in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

use Cwd;
app->static->paths->[0] = getcwd;

any '/' => sub {
  shift->render_static('index.html');
};

app->start;
```

Install Mojolicious: `curl get.mojolicio.us | sh` and then run `morbo server.pl`.

Should work, and you can tweak the script if you need to.

Comment: I don't like piping into a shell.

Comment: Ok then install via cpan: `cpan -i Mojolicious` or via apt (though it might be a little old. This is just a quick install script :-)

Comment: The one-liner version of that Mojolicious application would be: `perl -Mojo -E 'a->static->paths(["."]);a->start' daemon`

Comment: does't work. I can't see any directories. I get an error page with mojo. what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Twisted Web](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb):

```
twistd --pidfile= -n web --path .  --port 8080
```

`--pidfile=` disables the PID file. Without it a `twistd.pid` file will be created in the current directory. You can also use `--pidfile ''`.