# Error message 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP in AngularJS'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code:

```
MyAppModule.factory('EventData', function($http,$log){
    return {
        getEvent : function(successcb){

            $http({method: 'GET', url: './js/Services/products.json'}).

            success(function(data) {
                $log.info("success");
            }).
            error(function(data) {
                $log.info("error");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I have a simple JSON file in a local location, and I am trying to read it using the `http` method of [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS). I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Avraam/Documents/GitHub/AngularJS/app/js/Services/products.json Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. angular.min.js:73
>   Error: A network error occurred.

What is my mistake? I am not using any server; I am just openning my index file with Chrome. Is this the mistake? Should I use a server if I want to use the `http` method?

Comment: Yeah, you should setup an HTTP server application to host the page and JSON. Ajax isn't typically allowed with `file://`.

Comment: If you are having Python, you can start a server by running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from the directory containing index.html. The pages are accessible at 127.0.0.1:8000 and it will not have restrictions of a local page. Else, XAMPP or WAMP are anyway there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If this is for local development and you are using Chrome, you need to run Chrome with a couple of arguments to relax security like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Comment: And if you're running on a mac?

Comment: That isn't ideal, because Safari is not supported for what I'm working on, and Chrome is.

Comment: Serve the page using a local dev server and this restriction should not apply. Use XAMPP or if you have python, just run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and you should have a server running.

Comment: if i want to deploy my app what should i do?

Answer (score 15):

I fixed this problem by running my page off a server, like this

```
cd /path/to/dir/with/the/index/file
python3 -m http.server
```

then open http://localhost:8000 in your browser.

For other ways of serving the current directory, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328623).

Comment: You can enhance this workflow by using live-server, as you edit and save pages, it will automatically refresh your pages with the changes.

https://github.com/tapio/live-server

Answer (score 5):

For Mac users the respective command would be:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Update:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

[Source](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)

Comment: Using the --disable-web-security flag caused Chrome to give me some unsupported flag error. I removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in **Windows environment**, and use npm for package management the easiest is to install http-server globally:

`npm install -g http-server`

Then simply run http-server in any of your project directories:

`Eg. d:\my_project> http-server`

`Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http:169.254.116.232:8080
  http:192.168.88.1:8080
  http:192.168.0.7:8080
  http:127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server`

Easy, and no security risk of accidentally leaving your browser open vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for me. But before the command, you need to stop chrome process anyhow, can be from **task manager**

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Another way to make this working is as follows:
At first, Open **Run** by clicking: *Windows button + R*
Then, copy and paste the following command there:

```
 chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

This will open the chrome browser in disabled security mode and you can overcome that Errors.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can create a virtual host with WAMP or an other web development platform.

With I have no problems.

Answer (score -1):

run a http node server and serve the file.

1. Install connect and serve-static with NPM

   $ npm install connect serve-static
2. Create server.js file with this content:

   var connect = require('connect');
   var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
   connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080, function(){
       console.log('Server running on 8080');
   });
3. Run with Node.js

   $ node server.js

You can now go to the file that is doing cross-origin request without any error by going: http://localhost:8080/yourfile.html