# How to read a js script file from cjs chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iis, google-chrome-extension

I installed Google chrome extension cjs (Custom JavaScript for Website).

The script is working fine if I am writting the script inside the cjs editor:

[image]

I wrote the script in a js file and put it in my IIS as following:

- Open IIS Manager
- Right-click Default Web Site
- Add Application
- Alias = googleScript
- Physical path: C:\scripts\google (for example)
- I created a googleScript.js file and saved it in C:\scripts\google. The content of the file is:  *alert("Google")*;
- I clicked on Connect As and select *Application user (pass-through authentication)*
- I opened the *Default Document* located in the googleScript (in IIS) and Add a new Default Document named: googleScript.js
- When I right-click on googleScript and select *Manage Application->Browse*, a new web page is being opened with the script I wrote. THe url of the page is *http://localhost/googleScript/*
- Now back to cjs extension, instead of *alert("Google");* I wrote *//localhost/googleScript/googleScript.js;*.

[image]

When calling the script file, the alert is not working anymore. WHat is the correct way to call a script file from cjs chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

Read

- ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

before proceeding...

---

I created a small [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#8e15ac03380ce7f53593a06fea215555) you can use to experiment with this idea for your application/extension.

Now this is one way to grab and save an external scripts source online.

```
var download_to_textbox = function (url, el) {
      return $.get(url, null, function (data) {
        el.val(data)
      }, "text")
    };
```

Grab script source code and add it to a textarea

```
download_to_textbox('libraries/alertifyjs/css/alertify.min.css', $('.alertifyjs1'));
```

Save file using FileSaver.js - https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

```
var blob = new Blob([ $('.alertifyjs1').val() ], {type: "text/html"});
saveAs(blob, "alertify.min.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it on Chrome 85 with [Custom JavaScript for Websites 2, version 3.4.5](https://github.com/xcv58/Custom-JavaScript-for-Websites-2/releases/tag/v3.4.5). This isn't good to do permanently, the Chrome team had good reasons for disabling unsecured requests to localhost.

1. Enable chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost (paste that into the URL bar)
2. Add `http://localhost` to chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure and enable it
3. Restart Chrome
4. In a terminal window, create a directory containing your javascript file (let's say it's called `my-script-file.js`)
5. [Serve that directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109538) by `cd`'ing into it and running `python3 -m http.server`
6. add this line to cjs:

```
//localhost:8000/my-script-file.js
```

(`python3 -m http.server` serves on port 8000 by default)

7. click "Save" in the top left of the CJS popup

You should now see requests for //localhost:8000/my-script-file.js in the Network tab of the Chrome DevTools.